# Programming multiple FPGAs using JTAG

Tags: fpga, jtag, spartan

I have a JTAG chain connecting 4 Spartan 6 FPGAs that I program using ISE iMPACT. The software can program any strict subset of the 4 FPGAs in a row successfully, and in any order. However, when I attempt to program *all four* FPGAs, the DONE pin of the last FPGA does not go high, and the programming fails.

What could be causing this strange behaviour?

*Notes:*

1. After programming three of the FPGAs, the INIT_B bit of the status register for the fourth FPGA is 0, although the INIT_B pin is high. Right before programming the third FPGA, that bit was 1. This suggests the fourth FPGA has locked up.
2. When programming with SelectMap, I can program all four FPGAs without any problem.
3. When I program three of the FPGAs using SelectMap, the fourth one still cannot be programmed using JTAG.
4. Each of the four done pins are pulled-up to 3V3 through 4.7K Ohm resistors, and then tied together.

*Things I have tried*:

1. Disconnecting one of the FPGAs from the chain allows for the remaining 3 FPGAs to still be programmed.
2. Swapping the 4.7K Ohm pull-up resistor of the last FPGA for a 330 Ohm resistor doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "last FPGA"? Because in the User Guide is says `"The first device in a serial daisy chain is the last to be configured."` Do you mean last in the chain or last to be configured (first in the chain)? Could you provide a schematic?

Comment: This statement on p59 makes me think otherwise, `"If the Spartan-6 device is configured via JTAG, the configuration instructions occur independent from the mode pins."`

Comment: After familiarizing myself with the User Guide (it's been about 6 months since I've done FPGA work), I'm a bit confused by your terminology. Daisy Chain is used in conjunction with serial programming. In which case, the `DONE` pins are tied together. For JTAG, multiple device programming is called Boundary-Scan Chain. In `Chapter 3: Boundary-Scan and JTAG Configuration`, the only mention of the the `DONE` pin is `"If JTAG is the only configuration mode, then PROGRAM_B, INIT_B, and DONE can be tied High to a 330 resistor."` So is the `DONE` pin low the only problem? Does it program correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3902/discussion-between-embedded-kyle-and-randomblue)

Comment: I think the fact that you can get 3 but not 4 is a clue. Check out Chapter 4 of the JTAG Programmer Guide on Designing Boundary-Scan Systems: http://www.xilinx.com/support/sw_manuals/2_1i/download/jtag.pdf

Comment: @embedded.kyle: The fact that the status register is not being refreshed to reflect the correct status of `INIT_B` suggests that the fourth FPGA freezes: `Spartan (not the
SpartanXL) devices freeze if data errors occur during boundary-scan conﬁguration` (taken from Chapter 4).

Comment: It doesn't specifically mention the Status register, though I do agree with you. Have you tried a verify or an EXTEST as it suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out the culprit was the `INIT_B` pin. Although pulled high, as the first few FPGAs were programmed, the `INIT_B` pin was gradually pulled lower and lower because of an internal pull-down.

After three FPGAs were programmed, the `INIT_B` pin was pulled low enough for the fourth FPGA to interpret `INIT_B` as a logic low, thereby preventing the fourth FGPA to be programmed with JTAG.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the root cause. I kept checking this question for an answer since it was such odd behavior. What was the solution to the problem? A stronger pullup than the 330 \$\Omega\$?

Comment: It turns out there are bitgen options to specify that the `INIT_B` pin be pulled up instead of pulled down after programming.

Answer (score 6):

The `DONE` pin in not used during JTAG programming and can be tied high:

> If JTAG is the only configuration mode, then PROGRAM_B, INIT_B, and DONE can be 
>   tied High to a 330Ω resistor. (p57)

However, if Serial programming is used, then all the `DONE` pins should be tied together and the `DriveDone` should be disabled for all devices except the first:

> It is important to connect the DONE pins for all devices in a serial daisy chain. Failing to connect the DONE pins can cause configuration to fail. (p135)
>
> All devices except the first should disable the driver on the DONE pin. (p135)

If both are to be used, there are two options:

> Alternatively, the driver can be disabled for all DONE pins and an external pull-up resistor can be added to pull the signal High after all devices have released it. (p135)
>
> For debugging purposes, it is often helpful to have a way of disconnecting individual DONE pins from the common DONE signal, so that devices can be individually configured through the serial or JTAG interface. (p135)

In your case, I think connecting them and tying them all high while disabling the `DONE` pin is the best way to go.

All page numbers reference the [User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug380.pdf)

Comment: Hmmm...If you tied `INIT_B` high and the `INIT_B` bit in the status register is 0, that would indicate a hardware failure to me. Unless you can program that chip independently which I think you said you could. The `DONE` pin goes High-Z while programming so I don't know what the status register does during that point. If the previous FPGA status register's LSB is 1, then that indicates a CRC error in that device which may prevent programming of the next.

Comment: Problem found (see my solution). Thank you for your help.